# Does this equation have a closed form

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response

I am on chapter 6 of "Understanding digital signal processing", 3rd Edition by Richard G. Lyons. But I am stuck on question 6.15. Here is the network in question. [image]

I wrote down the difference  equation as $$y(n)=x(n)+y(n-1)-Qy(n-1),$$ where $x(n)=D$(i.e. constant for all $n$), $Q$ is positive and less than $1$ and network is at rest at $n=0$ (i.e $y(n-1)=0$ when $n=0.$) In order to answer the question, I need to develop the series equation for $y(n)$ and find its closed form.

I have developed the series expression for $$y(n)=D\sum^n_{k=0}(-Q)^k {{(n+1)}!\over{(k+1)!(n-k)!}}.$$

And the terms without simplifying the factorials are $$y(n)=D{(n+1)!\over n!} - DQ{(n+1)!\over 2(n-1)!} +DQ^2{(n+1)!\over 6(n-2)!} -DQ^3{(n+1)!\over 24(n-3)!} . .. +(-Q)^nD$$.

My issue is that I cannot find where I have gone wrong because this series for $y(n)$ does not seem to have a common ratio which makes it hard for me to write it in the closed form as in  $$\sum^{N-1}_{n=p}r^n={r^p-r^N\over{1-r}}.$$

My question is, is my developed $y(n)$ suitable? If it is suitable, does it have a closed form?

Thanks

Comment: i dunno why you don't combine $1$ and $-Q$ into $1-Q$.

Comment: or $Q-1$.  however you like it.  i don't understand why $Q$ should be by itself in any later equations.

Comment: is $x(n)=D=$ constant $\ne 0$ for all $n$ or just $n \ge  0$ ?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson sorry I have tried to improve the question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes $(x)$=D=constant and the question considers only $n$ greater or equals zero

Comment: why don't you combine $$y(n-1)-Qy(n-1)$$ into $(1-Q)y(n-1)$ ?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I had it that way but I ended up having to re-expand the brackets in order to obtain simplified values of $y(n)$ for $n=0,1,2,3...$.

Comment: if you want a closed form solution, i wouldn't bother with that.

Comment: A hint in the question says that I need it to develop the series expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y[n] = x[n] + (1-Q) y[n-1]$$

where $y[-1] = 0$ and otherwise $n \ge 0$.

this is a difference equation with both a *"natural response"* (when the input is always zero, but you might have initial conditions) and a *"forced response"*.  a.k.a. the *"transient response"* and the *"steady-state response"* the math guys might call these the *"homogeneous solution"* and the *"particular solution"*.

this is LTI so then the exponential function is an eigenfunction for the natural response.

for the natural solution, try 
$$ y_\text{n}[n] = y_\text{n}[0] a^n $$

then
$$\begin{align}
 y[n] &= x[n] + (1-Q) y[n-1] \\
 y_\text{n}[0] a^n &= 0 + (1-Q) y_\text{n}[0] a^{n-1} \\
               a^n &= (1-Q) a^{n-1} \\
                   &= (1-Q) a^n a^{-1} \\
               1   &= (1-Q) a^{-1} \\
\end{align}$$

so i guess $a = 1-Q$.

for steady state, you posit a solution that is like the input plus all of its finite differences.  since the input is constant and all finite differences of a discrete constant function are zero, then the steady state output is a constant.  you sum the scaled steady state with the scaled transient response for the complete response.

$$\begin{align}
 y[n] &= x[n] + (1-Q) y[n-1] \\
 C + y_\text{n}[0] a^n &= D + (1-Q)(C + y_\text{n}[0] a^{n-1}) \\
 C + y_\text{n}[0] (1-Q)^n &= D + (1-Q)(C + y_\text{n}[0] (1-Q)^{n-1}) \\
                           &= D + (1-Q)C + y_\text{n}[0] (1-Q)^n) \\
                      C &= D + (1-Q)C \\
\end{align}$$

i guess that means that $QC = D$ and $C = \tfrac{D}{Q}$.

now you add your natural response to your forced response.

$$ y[n] =  y_\text{n}[n] + C $$

lastly, for your initial condition

$$\begin{align}
 y[n] &= x[n] + (1-Q) y[n-1] \\
 y[0] &= x[0] + (1-Q) y[-1] \\
 C + y_\text{n}[0] (1-Q)^0 &= D + (1-Q)\cdot 0 \\
 C + y_\text{n}[0] &= D  \\
\end{align}$$

i guess that means that $ y_\text{n}[0] = D-C = D - \tfrac{D}{Q} $.

$$\begin{align}
  y[n] &= y_\text{n}[n] + C \\
       &= y_\text{n}[0]a^n + C \\
       &= (D - \tfrac{D}{Q})(1-Q)^n + \tfrac{D}{Q} \\
\end{align}$$

for $n \ge 0$.

Comment: As $n$ becomes large, the closed form becomes $D/Q$ as suggested by the book. I am not quite sure how I could have got this using the series expression as suggested by the book. It will take me a while (newbie here) but I am gonna try to understand what you have done which seem quite advanced for me! Any suggestion of what I can type into youtube?

Comment: you would have to recognize the series as that of an exponential function (and the constant term would be a little different).

Comment: you say you're a newbie.  have you had a class in differential equations?  although this is a finite difference equation (not having derivatives), the same concepts are used.  but any of these LTI difference equations will have exponentials in their solutions.

Comment: I did some classes years ago on differential equations, I will find and review, thanks a lot!